# Where to find information of functions in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

If I find a function I don't know, is there a website to quickly find out what's that function does.

Example I would like to see what `toList()` does? 
I tried to find in the cookbook but they always give a long example about the class instead of quick info of the function, unlike Python documentation website.

Comment: look into cake php docs: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html

Comment: I did, and it seems really hard to find information of some function. Example the function name toList()? Many example in cookbook use toList() but non mention what it does.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking "where is [the api](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/)?" Everything there is also in the source code.